# A dedicated property in a type does not exist on union

Tags: typescript

First have a look at the code

```
type TBasedInfo = {
  name: 'getBasedQuery';
  params: {
    market: string;
    items: string;
    year?: string;
  };
};

type TGetShopDetail = {
  name: 'getShopDetail';
  params: {
    market: string;
    items: string;
    shopName: string;
    year?: string;
  };
};

type TGetCarDetail = {
  name: 'getCarDetail';
  params: {
    market: string;
    items: string;
    car: string;
    year?: string;
  };
};

type TMsRequest = TGetCarDetail | TGetShopDetail | TBasedInfo;

function getRequest(request: TMsRequest) {
  switch (request['name']) {
    case 'getShopDetail':
      const { shopName } = request['params'];
      console.log(shopName);
    case 'getCarDetail':
      const { car } = request['params'];
      console.log(car);
  }
}
```

I got the error `Property 'car' does not exist on type '{ market: string; items: string; shopName: string; year?: string; } | { market: string; items: string; car: string; year?: string; }'.ts(2339)`, which is dedicated field for type `TGetCarDetail`. But this issue didn't happen to another dedicated field `shopName`.

Would you all share your thoughts, and how to fix in this case.

Comment: Add a `break;` before `case 'getCarDetail':` and see the magic!

Comment: @KunalKukreja It looks like your answer works. You should post your comment as an answer, to allow this question to be resolved.

Comment: This is a typo question that is mostly irrelevant to TypeScript and is about the fall-through behavior of `switch` when one forgets to add a `break` in a `case` clause. Please vote for closing as "not reproducible or caused by a typo".

Comment: Oops, my bad comment, sorry for wasting your time